# Add jButton to JxTreeTable cell

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, swingx, jxtreetable

I have a JxTreeTable with four columns . First column has laboratory test names. Second column status of tests ie initially "pending". I need a buttons namely "send" and "complete" in third and fourth column respectively. When i click "send" button against a test ,status must change from "pending" to "waiting" and when i click "complete" button status must change from "waiting" to "complete". I created a JxTreeTable programmatically and added test name and status "pending" to JxtreeTable.

Now, how can I add Jbutton to third and fourth cell of JxtreeTable and how to change status by clicking thos buttons in cell.

Help me to sort this problem.

Comment: sir, I need to add buttons to JxTreeTable. How to do this? help me..

Comment: read related question, it helps you. At SO a lot of questins about `JButton` column, also examine [`TableButtonColumn`](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) by camickr.